# Angular 5 Understanding External Class Imports

Tags: angular, class, typescript

I have created a class model for Schedules. I then import this class into my main program. My problem is that this class uses the HttpClient and the way I was taught to use it is to create the variable for it inside the constructor of the class. But the problem then comes in, when I create a new instance of the Schedule (newSchedule = new Schedule;) then it expects a parameter in the place of the HttpClient. How do I make it ignore the HttpClient when I want to create a new instance of the class?

Here is the Schedule model class:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
export class Schedule {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
}
```

But now I need to pass this.HttpClient in my main program, which of course is not needed:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
    var NewSchedule = new Schedule(this.HttpClient);
}
```

How do I remove the need to pass this.HttpClient? I assume my process is quite wrong

Comment: its a bit strange that your model class needs `HttpClient` service. If `Schedule` is your model then you should have something like `ScheduleService` which should have `HttpClient` injected and its methods should return `Schedule`, `Schedule[]` or whatever you get from http calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your process seems indeed wrong. But you ask for help, so we provide.

You need to make the parameter of the constructor optional. Do like so :

```
export class Schedule {
  constructor(private http?: HttpClient){}
}
```

You can also give it a default value :

```
export class Schedule {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient = null){}
}
```

Comment: Thank you this solves my problem perfectly! Just as a follow up question, say I have 3 parameters constructor(x, y?, z). Then when I create a new instance, Test("blue", 13), to which parameters will blue and 13 be assigned to?

Comment: You will have 3 parameters (x, y, z?). You can't put an optional parameter in the middle. IF you have an IDE, it will warn you. All the optional and "defaulted" parameters will go at the end of the list !

Comment: Ah cool thanks!...I see now this code doesn't work though. If I do new Schedule() without passing the HttpClient, then my this.httpClient.get doesn't work inside the class "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Comment: Ah damn, cause this is how you create HttpClients in angular...I need a solution for this then

Comment: You asked for something, I delivered. HttpClient is a singleton, and the fact that you're putting it as a dependency in your classes is the reason your process is wrong. I answered the question you asked, if you have another one then make another question. But before, you should learn how to use Typescript and Angular. That's not the same as using Java or any other object oriented language.

Comment: By the way, when someone answers your question and you mark it as resolved, then you have another question, the courtesy and way to go is to not remove the resolved mark and make another question. Now I don't really want to help you anymore.

Comment: I meant no hard man, at first I thought your answer would work until I used it and then I saw it doesn't work. Do you use Angular? If you use Angular, like my title says, then this solution doesn't help anyone else either so there is no point in me marking it as the answer. I meant no hard man :)

Comment: @Frank : So you actually need the HTTP client inside the Schedule's object? Why don't you make Schedule injectable? and inject it in `AppComponent`?

Comment: I use Angular, and you asked `How do I make it ignore the HttpClient when I want to create a new instance of the class ?` : the answer is to make the parameters optional. The answer fits the request, it is your question that doesn't fit your need. You have a structure flow, that's your issue, not mine. Anyway, good luck with your issue.

Comment: @AshishRanjan because he needs several instances of the class, not a singleton. He precised that into a  deleted answer (that you can see when you have enough reputation)

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks man. If no one else gives it a try I will mark yours as the answer just to say thanks. I understand that my question might be wrong but there is no point in me marking it correct if everyone else ends up having the same problem I have now. I would've asked a question like "How to make parameters optional" if I wanted your answer. Sorry man but thanks, appreciate the help.

Comment: @trichetriche: Oh Okay, got it.

Comment: @Frank: See, if my solution helps you?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, what I understood is, you want to have different instances of the `Schedule` class but still want to access the `httpClient` object.

Doing the following may be one solution:

Make a public method under the `Schedule` class:

```
public getNewInstance(object: Object) {
    let obj = Object.create(object.constructor.prototype);
    object.constructor.apply(obj, [this.httpClient]);
    return obj;
}
```

Also make your `Subject` class injectable. Please note, Your class will be an injectable and an singleton inside another classes, but you will have a way to get several instances using that singleton

DO something like:

```
@Injectable()
export class Schedule ...
```

Then, In your appComponent, inject `Subject`.

```
export class AppComponent {
constructor(private subjectInstance: Subject) {}
...

private newSubjectInstance;
ngOnInit() {
    this.newSubjectInstance = this.subjectInstance.getNewInstance(this.subjectInstance);
    // so this should be a new instance but still have the httpClent inside it.
}
```

Comment: That's literally going against angular patterns. That's not a solution, that's a workaround, and (in my opinion) not a good one.

Comment: @trichetriche: When you said, its going against angular patterns and not  a good wrok around in your opinion, can you please direct me for some reference as to why you said so, I will look into that later today.

Comment: Well start with the definition of a Singleton and what the @Injectable operator does.